# Overlapping labels on ggplot image embedded in pdf by knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

I have a .Rmd file that I can use to construct standard reports containing graphs and tables. The script works as intended with knitr when rendering a .html file, but if I want to render a .pdf file I can run into situations where the x-axis labels for graphs can overlap. For example:

Html output:

[image: Output in a html report.]

Pdf output:
[image: Output in a pdf report.]

I know I can set the output image size for the ggplot figure like so:

````
```{r, fig.width=10,fig.height=11}
...
```
````

But this isn't really ideal as the label names can change and it quite often is the case that there is no overlap. I would hate to implement a change to the format that impacts all of the other graphs that do not have this problem. Is there any way to intelligently identify if this kind of overlap is occurring and only then make an adjustment?

Comment: have you tried using `scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)` to shorten the longer labels?